# Vue + DRF - best way to get user

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a blogging app which is using Vue + DRF. I have a new post component, but i'm not sure which way is the best to pass post author to backend. There is a store used in frontend so it's possible to pass author with rest of post data, but there is also possibility to get user from request by overriding `create` method in post view set. The side effect from second method is that it's impossible to create new post as different than logged user via rest api panel so it's the reason why i'm wondering about it. What should i do in this case?

Comment: You need to think about it from the perspective of your API. What information does it already have, what does it need? It should already know who the authenticated user is, so you don’t need to pass that information explicitly. Unless of course you want the user to be able to override the supposed author of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is a standard blogging app I would go for the second solution, you probably do not want your users to be able to write posts under a different account that their own and you will add complexity in your vue app. Plus if you are using DRF you don't event need to override the create method. DRF provides you with convenient methods to set implicit attributes in requests. Here for instance you could set the author of a post by adding this in your view/viewset

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```